# multiple threading with SurfaceView

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I am able to display single video using SurfaceView in android. Now I want to display multiple video using SurfaceView. So, my question is that should I create multiple SurfaceView for multiple video or a single SurfaceView can be multi-threaded ?

Comment: want to play multiple videos at a time or one by one?

Comment: @Abhi Thanks for responce... I want to display multiple videos at the same time.I this possible with single SurfaceView?

Comment: I would suggest you to take videoview to play video if you want to play n videos in same layout put n videoview in xml, careful about Memory leaks

Comment: @Abhi I can not use VideoView because I am displaying video just by frame by frame.

Comment: come to [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people) we can discuss there.., i didnt get the frame by frame displaying

Answer (score 0):

I would have a separate surface view for each video, each with their own thread. Be careful of memory leaks with multi threading